# Sequelize cascade onDelete by migration - how do I set this?

Tags: sequelize.js

I am working with a database that is already established. The original migration contained an addConstraint command that did not set the onDelete to cascade, so it defaulted to not do so. Realizing that this prevents the deletion of items, I have been tasked with fixing it.

I created a migration that first deletes and then recreates those constraints in exactly the same manner but with the onDelete and the hooks set to cascade and true. The problem is that after running the migration this is not working and I have no idea why.

I am getting the error ...

```
Key (id)=(x) is still referenced from table "races"
```

- Do I need to alter the init-models file? If so, do this manually or via a command line of some kind? Do I need to run a command after altering it?
- Do I need to alter the model at the same time? If so, how? I'm not aware of a migration command to do this. I've used them to add or remove columns but not to adjust a property on a model. Is this deleting the model and then reestablishing it with the onDelete and hooks set?

My migration file :

```
"use strict";

/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.removeConstraint("races", "races_election_fk");
    await queryInterface.removeConstraint("candidates", "candidates_race_fk");
    await queryInterface.removeConstraint(
      "area_reports",
      "area_reports_race_fk"
    );

    await queryInterface.addConstraint("races", {
      fields: ["election_id"],
      type: "foreign key",
      name: "races_election_fk",
      references: {
        table: "elections",
        field: "id",
      },
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
      hooks: true,
    });

    await queryInterface.addConstraint("candidates", {
      fields: ["race_id"],
      type: "foreign key",
      name: "candidates_race_fk",
      references: {
        table: "races",
        field: "id",
      },
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
      hooks: true,
    });

    await queryInterface.addConstraint("area_reports", {
      fields: ["race_id"],
      type: "foreign key",
      name: "area_reports_race_fk",
      references: {
        table: "races",
        field: "id",
      },
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
      hooks: true,
    });
  },

  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    /**
     * Add reverting commands here.
     *
     * Example:
     * await queryInterface.dropTable('users');
     */
  },
};
```